# "Error: non-static variable this cannot be referenced from a static context" in calculation class

Tags: java

My instance of the class "Conversion" returns this error when I compile the program.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Convert {

    private class Conversion{

        public String getConversion(int inchInput) {
            int yards = (inchInput - (inchInput % 36)) / 36;
            int feet =  (inchInput % 36) - ((inchInput % 36) % 12);
            int inches = (inchInput % 36) % 12;

            return yards + "yards, " + feet + "feet, and " + inches + "inches.";
        }

    } // end of class Conversion

    public static void main( String[] args ) {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        int inchInput;
        Conversion conversion;
        conversion = new Conversion();

        // prompt
        System.out.println("Please enter an amout of inches (integer): ");
        inchInput = scanner.nextInt();
        String output = conversion.getConversion(inchInput);
    } // end of method main()
} // enf of class Convert
```

Comment: On what line is the exception occuring?

Answer (score 2):

`Conversion` is inner class to `Convert`.So you can't access it directly.
You need to create `Conversion` object like this.

```
Convert convert =new Convert();
Conversion conversion;
conversion = convert.new Conversion();
```

or declare the `Conversion` as static

```
 class Convert {
   private static class Conversion{
     ...............
      ............
  }
}
```

and create `Conversion` object like this

```
Conversion conversion = new Convert.Conversion();
```

Answer (score 2):

Make the `Conversion` class `static` so that there is an accesible enclosed instance of the class

```
private static class Conversion {
  ...
}
```

Comment: ...or move it outside, as general-purpose classes would be.

Comment: There's some more helpful explanation here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/70324/java-inner-class-and-static-nested-class

Answer (score 1):

set modifier of class to static

```
private static class Conversion
```

at

Answer (score 0):

You need probably:

```
Convert.Conversion cc = new Convert().new Conversion();
cc.getConversion(...);
...
```